# I have an error when creating a Connection in android studio

Tags: java, android, postgresql

I have a class named DataBase and inside i have this method that will create an object of connection
tried to make it run in a seperate thread from the UI Thread but it still blocks it and makes the application not responding

I tried not running it in a different thread but it gives me an exception that basically says it should'nt be executed on the main thread

here is the method:

```
public Connection createConnection(){
        DatabaseConnection dataBaseConnection = new DatabaseConnection(url,user,password,connection);
        Thread dbThread = new Thread(dataBaseConnection);

        dbThread.start();

        try{
            dbThread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dataBaseConnection.getConnection();
    }
```